# iphone - uitableview cell did not update on iPhone but on iPad yes

Tags: ios, tableview, reload

I have universal app with tableview and I'm parsing items init. When I parse new data, I use `[tableView reloadData]` to reload data in tableView. When I run app on iPad, reload works well, when on iPhone, it reload data, but title of cell is still that old... Any ideas, why it is doing that? Thanks

Comment: No idea.. Just show your code.

Comment: I got it.. Just declare tableview to .h file... :-)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got it... You must have declared that UItableview in header file for use `[tableView reload]` outside configure part of UITableView... So easy - I have declared tableView as table and than, I call `[table reloadData]` :-)